# How to bold & add "*" to TextBlock when Tab Can be saved

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have tabs representing documents, something like in Word. My `TabControl` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`. `TabViewModel` has a property `CanSave` indicating whether a document can be save. When it can be saved, I want to bold it and prefix it with an "*". How can I do this? I think I need to 1st make `CanSave` a `DependencyProperty`. And add a trigger. But what about prefix the "*"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a `DependencyProperty`; you just need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

You can bind the property to the `Visibility` of a separate `<TextBlock>*</TextBlock>` and to the weight of the title using triggers.

Comment: If I want to refernece a property in XAML won't I need to use DependencyProperties?

Comment: No, you don't.  You only need to make a DependencyProperty if you want to bind that property to a value (not if you want to bind a different property to its value)

Comment: DependencyObject implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and at its core, that is how a dependency property works--it sends change notifications via the interface

Comment: Hmm, how might the code look like? sorry, I am still relatively new to more advanced WPF. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A simple (maybe ugly, but should definitely work):

```
void CanSave(....)
{
   bool canSave = GetValueBlahBlah();
   if (tb.IsVisible != canSave)
       tb.Visibility = canSave ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

`tb` represents the TextBlock you wanna show and hide according to the CanSave state.

You might also wanna create a DependencyProperty as you said and set the `TextBlock` s (you will have to use a separate TextBlock for the star - or use `Run`s which are bindable in WPF 4+) `Visibility`/`FontWeight` according to it via `DataTrigger`s.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the titles of your tabs via binding....

```
<TabControl >
   <TabItem >
          <TabItem.Header>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle1}" />
          <TabItem.Header>
</TabControl>
```

and then set the title on your data model

```
Tab1Title="* " + "some nice tab title";
```

you could also use binding to set the font to bold....

```
FontWeight="{Binding Tab1FontWeight}"
```